# Overflow hidden property is not working with parallax scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

The overflow hidden property is not working as expected when trying it with parallax scrolling.

I am trying to accomplish parallax scrolling with JavaScript everything should work fine but when i try to set the overflow to hidden the image still appearing outside the div

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="page2">
       <p id="bb">The title</p> //Some title
       <div id="bg"></div> //Blue box in front of the image(design decision)
       <img src="img/Food.jpg" alt="prlx" id="prlx"/> //The image which has the proprety
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript eventListener and the function :

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",func,false);

function func(){
      prlx_lyr_1 = document.getElementById("prlx");
      prlx_lyr_1.style.top = (window.pageYOffset/4)+"px"
}
```

And this is my CSS for the image which i am trying to hide the overflowing parts :

```
#page2 img{
      position:relative;
      top:-300px;
}
```

And this is the CSS of the div which contain the image

```
#page2{
      overflow:hidden;
      height:250px;
}
```

There is some extra CSS for the #bg

**Update:**
   here is a [image: screenshot to better explain]

You can notice that the overflow is not hidden the container div is the blue side in the page

Here is a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubcq92gz/4/)

Comment: can you recreate in a fiddle? It's hard to tell what you mean by `The overflow hidden property is not working as expected`

Comment: I tried explaining as much as i can i am trying to make a parallax but it wont work only with fixed value to the position property so I sat it to fixed and in the div i added overflow:hidden but the image still not hidden outside the div

Comment: can you post a link then? its just to hard to tell what's going on with what you provided

Comment: @jmore009 i added a screenshot to better explain check out the update

Comment: Thanks but without actually getting in there to inspect the issue it's really difficult to tell. Unless you can post a link or recreate this issue in something like jsfiddle it's going to be hard to get a good answer

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ubcq92gz/4/ here is jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is `position: fixed` breaks the element out of the flow of the document and unlike `absolute` it can't be contained by using `relative` on a parent. Instead you should set this image as a `background` set to `fixed` on a `div` that is `position: absolute`:

**HTML**

```
<div id="page2">
   <p id="bb">The chef</p>
   <div id="bg"></div>
   <div id="bg-image"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#page2{
  overflow:hidden;
  height:250px;
  position: relative;
}

#bg{
  background: #33c1c9;
  height:250px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  z-index:74897;
  opacity:0.4;
}

#bg-image{
  background: url("http://im47.gulfup.com/1Y5tcL.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ubcq92gz/6/)

Comment: Thank you so much i did think about this this group is just awesome :)